# Has Windows 10 update 1903 affected the Start Menu for anyone else?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd

Following are my laptop specs (MSI GL63 8RE):

- CPU: Intel Core i7 8750H (8th gen)
- GPU 1: NVIDIA GTX 1060 6GB
- GPU 2: Intel UHD Graphics 630
- RAM: 16GB @2666MHz
- SSD: 128GB (for OS only: Win10 Pro 64-bit)
- HDD: 1TB @7200rpm
- Drivers: ALL concerned drivers are up-to-date

First time poster but long time PC user.

**Issue:** Whenever I click on the windows button right after boot up, the Start Menu pops up lightning fast just like it should especially considering I've got menu start up delay at 50ms. However, once I've started doing some work on my laptop & then click on the windows button to access the Start Menu, it takes nearly 2secs for it to popup.

**What I think the reason is:** The latest Windows update (1903) included a separate process for the Start Menu. Maybe it has something to do with that ? But considering my specs, this issue shouldn't occur anyway. Please help. I've formatted my HD then reinstalled everything. I have a very minimalistic approach so I've uninstalled all the Windows apps that can be uninstalled & there is no MSI bloatware on my laptop only the bear essentials.

Answer (score 0):

The start menu doesn't open any slower for me but it opens slightly to the right of where it normally would.